# What does kernel-wedge do?

Tags: debian, kernel, deb

After looking at the package description and using `kernel-wedge help`, I'm not really sure what it does.  Does it take a `.deb` kernel package and split it into smaller packages?  Does it compile a kernel and turn it into a `.deb` package?  Both?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [manpage](http://man.devl.cz/man/1/kernel-wedge):

> ```
> kernel-wedge is used to generate kernel module udebs for the debian installer.
> ```

What it does is take a regular kernel image deb and then split it out into udebs.

---

[`udebs`](http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/doc/internals/ch03.html) are packages used by the Debian installer and are like regular `deb` packages except that things that are not needed for bootstrapping an installation, but would be useful on a regular install, are removed to save space.

> Some core Debian packages are available as udebs (“micro debs”), and are typically used only for bootstrapping a Debian installation. Although these files use the udeb filename extension, they adhere to the same structure specification as ordinary deb files. However, unlike their deb counterparts, udeb packages contain only essential functional files.[[2](http://d-i.alioth.debian.org/doc/internals/ch03.html)] In particular, documentation files are normally omitted.

— [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)#Design)

Comment: Okay, but the `build-all` and `build-arch` sub-commands makes it sound like it can also compile the kernel, while `install-files` makes it sound like it build the `.deb` file which eventually gets split into `.udeb` files.

Comment: the `build` prefix in `build-arch` and `build-all` refers to building the udeb package itself. For instance, see this [README](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/d-i/kernel-wedge.git/tree/README) from the `kernel-wedge` git repo.

Comment: You can also look at the scripts in the `commands` directory, but `install-files` populates the build directory, and the build commands actually builds the udeb package.